# Input validation of opening a text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, validation, input, filestream

I am building an input validation function that takes the input of the user and tries to open that file. and repeats if user is not entering the correct format. the correct format is:

> *test1.txt*

My function works if I write correct format in the first run, but after the second run it keeps printing the error message although I am writing the write format to be opened. I have tried to clear the input "cin" and "filename" after taking the input but it did not work. Any ideas ?

```
string getFileInput()
{
    string filename;
    fstream file;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the file: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    while(!file.is_open())
    {
        file.clear(); file.ignore();
        cout << "File name is incorrect, please enter again: ";
        cin.clear(); cin.ignore();

        getline(cin, filename);
        file.open(filename.c_str());
    }
    // Extra condition. Empty file
    if (file.eof())
    {
        cout << filename << " is an empty file." << endl;
    }
    file.close();
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: `file.open` can fail for many reasons other than an invalid file name.  Suppose the user does not have read permission on the file.  In that case, printing "File name in incorrect" is not  useful.

Comment: `file.eof()` will be false immediately after `file.open` even when the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce and fix.

The problem is caused by `cin.ignore()`. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

> ... the next available character c in the input sequence is delim

So `ignore` will read the next line, up to the newline, and *leave that newline alone*. And the following `getline` can only read an empty string!

By the way, using a non opened `fstream` (`file`) for `ignore` and `clear` is at least useless and could be harmlfull because those methods are expected to be called on an open stream. And using `cin.clear()` is useless too and can be harmfull: if for any reason you have a read error (because you reached an end of file for example), you will consistently clear the error condition and try to read again when you should abort.

Finally, the `eof` condition is only set **after** a read returned nothing because of the end of file. It is never set when opening an empty file, nor if you could successfully read up to the end of file.

So the function should boil down to:

```
string getFileInput()
{
    string filename;
    fstream file;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the file: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    if (! cin) {
        // test the error immediately and before using filename!
        cerr << "read error: aborting...\n";
        return "";
    }
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    while(!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File name is incorrect, please enter again: ";

        getline(cin, filename);
        if (! cin) {
            // test the error immediately and before using filename!
            cerr << "read error: aborting...\n";
            return "";
        }
        file.open(filename.c_str());
    }
    file.close();
    return filename;
}
```